# HIghcharts: Hide particular Bar in Bar chart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, hide, bar-chart

I want to Hide particular bar on condition instead of white color of bar. Here i am uploading snippet of my code.

```
            name: 'Series 1',
            data: [0.45,0.36,0.78,0.49,0.59,0.75],
                 dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: 10,
                        textOutline: false
                    },
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 12,
                    y: -1,

                    formatter: function () {
                        if (this.y <= 0.49) {

                            this.point.color = "white";
                        }
                        return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                    }
                }, pointPadding: 0, groupPadding: 0.05, pointPlacement: 0,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        color: 'rgb(204,204,204)',
                        enabled: true
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here i am giving JSFiddle Link:- http://jsfiddle.net/s76yrwwm/2/

Comment: If you want points to be present on a chart but not visible, instead of white color use transparent (http://jsfiddle.net/L761meyu/).

Comment: @d_paul this is works and I also want to point to be absent in my chart whose value is less than 0.50

Comment: Put "formatter" into tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/6qkqqn9t/

Comment: @manuzi1 thanks but i want hide bar while chart is load

Comment: var bar = main_insight_graph.series[0].data[this.y];
bar.graphic.hide();
i also tried this but not working

Comment: If you want to get rid of points entirely from the chart, you can put null at their places. Also, if you want to do something on chart load, place it inside chart.events.load function (http://jsfiddle.net/t0qyfbgy/).

Comment: @d_paul Thanks it's working 98% my issue solved.

Comment: @d_paul can you give me your email id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved link by **D_Paul** for my question Here it is [jsfiddle][1] .

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/t0qyfbgy`enter code here`